# Laravel 5: how can I retrieve and display all posts that belong to certain category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
user:       id, username
subreddits: id, name, created_at
posts:      id, title, link, user_id, subreddit_id
```

The problem is, I am fetching the id of the subreddit / category manually while I need to be fetching it dynamically. How can I achieve that?

This is the `show()` method in SubredditController.php

```
public function show(Subreddit $subreddit)
    {

        $posts = Subreddit::findOrFail(3)->posts()->get();

        return view('subreddit/show')->with('subreddit', $subreddit)
                                    ->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

And this is Subreddit Model

```
class Subreddit extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
$router->model('articles', 'App\Article');
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
$router->model('posts', 'App\Post');
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the argument passed to your `show()` method to be the ID of the post? How do you want to get the ID?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamically" ?

Comment: As you can from the above, I'm getting `Subreddit::findOrFail(3)` so whenever I visit `http://localhost/laravel-5/public/subreddit/4` or any other subreddit id, I get the posts associated with Subreddit id = 3

Comment: im really confused why you injected an instance of Subreddit in your function show.

Comment: @Halnex Instead of passing an instance of your model via method injection `show(Subreddit $subreddit){ ... }`, add an $id parameter `show($id){ ... }`. This should then be accessible within the method.

Comment: @Jeemusu I tried that, everyone suggested that but it's not working. It gives me `No query results for model [App\Subreddit].` - This was suggested by @HotRod below.

Comment: @Halnex Try to debug, you are getting that exception because you are using `firstOrFail()`. This throws an exception when no results are returned. Try doing a `dd($id);` at the top of the `show()` method. Does it output the value of the `$id` parameter from the URI?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, it returned an array with the subreddit's information, mainly `name` and `description`

Comment: wait... Are you using route model binding? You should post any applicable code from your routes.php

Comment: @Jeemusu yes. `$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');`

Comment: in that case you can access the id via `$subreddit->id`. ignore all the previous advice.

Comment: @Jeemusu I've updated my original post, there's nothing more to my routes.php

Comment: @Jeemusu woohoo!!! That's it!! oh my god, I've been at it for 12 hours. Please update your reply below so I can select it as the answer. And a question, am I doing it right? I read many people asking me why am I injecting my model in my method, is this bad practice?

Comment: @Halnex Your doing just fine! Thats how Route Model binding works in Laravel. I'm guessing most people haven't used it (myself included), which might make your code look a little odd at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Route Model Binding, Laravel will automatically retrieve an object for the $id provided in the URI, which can then be injected into your method as an argument using dependency injection.

```
public function show(Subreddit $subreddit){ ... }
```

You can access the data as you would any object. E.g. To access the id of the record you can use `$subreddit->id`.

```
public function show(Subreddit $subreddit)
{
    $posts = Subreddit::findOrFail($subreddit->id)->posts()->get();

    return view('subreddit/show')->with('subreddit', $subreddit)
                                    ->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Comment: I tried that too, I get the error `Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\SubredditController::show() must be an instance of App\Subreddit, none given`

Comment: @Halnex Try switching the order of the arguments in the show() method...seems like it expects the second one to be your model for some reason.

Comment: @Halnex Out of interest, why are you injecting the Subreddit Model into your `show()` method? Try removing it all together.

Comment: Please update your reply so I can select it as the answer, it will help others researching the issue maybe.

Comment: @Halnex Updating now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new with Laravel, but I think you need to define a route with parameters (sorry if I misunderstood your question).

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters

Comment: this is what I assumed as well, but I was waiting for OP to confirm before posting an answer as a guess :)

Comment: and unfortunately you beat me to it. +1

Comment: As you can from the above, I'm getting `Subreddit::findOrFail(3)` so whenever I visit `http://localhost/laravel-5/public/subreddit/4` or any other subreddit id, I get the posts associated with Subreddit id = 3

Comment: But I already have these routes defined
    `Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id using your route.

In your routes.php file, you can have this:

```
Route::get('subreddit/{id}', 'SubredditController@show');
```

And in SubredditController.php, pass the id to your method, like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $subreddit = Subreddit::findOrFail($id);
    $posts = $subreddit->posts()->get();

    return view('subreddit/show')->with('subreddit', $subreddit)
                                 ->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Comment: That won't and did not work. I got `Undefined variable: subreddit` because if I remove `Subreddit $subreddit` from the `show()` method, I won't be able to access `$subreddit->posts()` and I already have `Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');`

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you are passing the `$id` through `show( )`? Try this: Add the namespace at the top of your file `use App\Subreddit;` or whatever your Subreddit namespace is. Then use the show function just like in the answer.

Comment: I was already using `use App\Subreddit;` but then changed it to your code and I got this error `No query results for model [App\Subreddit].`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are typing the model to the parameter of the function?

```
show(Subreddit $subreddit)
```

I saw it somewhere, but I cannot remember the need to use it.

are you using the column `id` autoincrement in the database?, if not, you have to especify it in the model adding the property incrementing and set it to false

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

and specify the actual primarykey

```
protected $primaryKey = 'code';
```

With the configuration that you posted, this code works for me:

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('subreddit', 'SubredditController');
```

**SubredditController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $subreddit = Subreddit::findOrFail($id);
    $subreddit->load('posts');
    return view("subreddit/show")->with("subreddit", $subreddit);
}
```

**url**

```
http://localhost:8888/test/public/subreddit/1
```

I'm loading the relation in the same object so send only one param to the view

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work. I got the same error as before `No query results for model [App\Subreddit].`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is **route model binding**

If you are using laravel 5, jeff way happens to have a very good tutorial for it [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/18)

[here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding) is also the documentation for route model binding.

Good news is Route model Binding is also flexible, even binding a complex data subset from your model to the route. which i think will fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch category with all posts

```
$categories = Subreddit::with('posts') -> where('id',$id) -> first(); 
if (categories){
  $data['results'] = categories;
}else{
  $data['results'] = null;
}

return view('myview') -> with($data);
```

The variable `$results` will be accessible in your view. 
In your view

```
if (!is_null($results){
  foreach($results as $result){
    // do something.
  }
}
```

Hooe this help.

Comment: Your code forces me to change the parameter of the `show()` method from `Subreddit $subreddit` to `$id` but that in itself creates a new problem `Undefined variable: results`

Comment: Thank you mate, but it's been solved. I should've been accessing the id via `$subreddit->id` that's it :)